# Is it true that scrum masters are paid better than data analysts and data scientists?

Tags: scrum-master, data-science

So I saw somewhere that scrum masters are paid more than data analysts and data scientists and that the average salary is even significantly higher. On average they are even paid 30k a year more.
I was wondering if this is true and why?

You need more skill and knowledge to do data science, data engineering or data analysis. Is it one of those typical things that the ones who actually add value and are the most important get valued less?

Comment: Notwithstanding your biases, you need to get a handle on supply and demand and the effects on wages and quantity. The answer is there. Should be easy to understand if you're a skilled data analyst.

Comment: This is a question that is unsuitable for PMSE, but that can be easily answered by a salary guide such as those put out annually by organizations like Salary.com or Robert Half. *Why* is largely irrelevant; that's just a supply and demand issue, but I suspect that in most markets the technical specialties will have higher *median* rates, but your local markets and personal experiences will vary.

Comment: See [Expert Agile Scrum Master](https://www.salary.com/tools/salary-calculator/expert-agile-scrum-master?yrs=12) & [DevOps Architect](https://www.salary.com/tools/salary-calculator/devops-architect/san-francisco-ca?yrs=12) for examples of how to research this and compare skill sets, markets, and so forth. It's still lies, damned lies, and statistics, but it's the only way a question like this can be answered canonically (if at all).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if what you say is true, but it might be understandable because SM is a leadership role requiring people and organizational skills that often attract a premium. Many SMs are also highly experienced in engineering, analysis and/or data science. The SM role doesn't have to exclude those disciplines because some SMs continue to perform such functions as part of a development team. Lastly of course, supply and demand are major factors influencing rates of pay.

Comment: The question has been closed, but in my personal experience salary guides show senior technical people getting paid more than senior project managers of whatever type. For example: https://www.salary.com/tools/salary-calculator/expert-agile-scrum-master?yrs=12 and https://www.salary.com/tools/salary-calculator/devops-architect/san-francisco-ca?yrs=12 show that the *median* delta is +$61k for the technologist in San Francisco. Your answer may not be universally wrong, so I'm not down-voting, but this kind of guesswork is one reason I closed the OP's question as opinion-generating and off-topic.